# Is there a way to equally level the <div class ="card"> in bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, frontend

I'm struggling on how to level this card equally to each other:

[image]

As you can see in the picture below. The card for the top reason for downtime doesn't match what is on the other cards or vice-versa. I want them to on the same height with each other regardless of what is inside on them.

Below is my code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                        <h5 class="card-header">
                            Top Reason for downtime
                        </h5>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <ul id="top5Downtime">

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                        <h5 class="card-header">
                            Top Down Terminals:
                        </h5>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <ol id="mostDown">

                            </ol>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                        <h5 class="card-header">
                            Top Up Terminals:
                        </h5>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <ol id="mostUp">

                            </ol>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--End of div.row-->

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="card shadow mb-5">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div id="bar-chart">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--End of div.row-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="card shadow mb-5">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div id="lineChart">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="card shadow mb-3">
                        <h5 class="card-header">
                            Planned vs Unplanned Event
                        </h5>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div id="pieChart"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="card shadow mb-3">
                        <h5 class="card-header">
                            Downtime vs Uptime
                        </h5>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div id="pieChart2"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="card shadow mb-5">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div id="barChart2">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="card shadow mb-5">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div id="barChart3">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--END OF div.row-->
            <!--END OF div.row-->
        </div>
```

I've tried using the `align-self-stretch` but it only broke my design.  How could I proceed?

Comment: What about using `flex-row` instead of just `row` (in combination with setting up `align-items-stretch` on those cards?

Answer (score 0):

Applying `display: flex` (or `.d-flex` class) to each of the `.col`s in same row will make them have equal height:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 d-flex">
      <div class="card shadow mb-4 w-100">
        <h5 class="card-header">
          Top Reason for downtime
        </h5>
        <div class="card-body">
          <ul id="top5Downtime">

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 d-flex">
      <div class="card shadow mb-4 w-100">
        <h5 class="card-header">
          Top Down Terminals:
        </h5>
        <div class="card-body">
          <ol id="mostDown">

          </ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 d-flex">
      <div class="card shadow mb-4 w-100">
        <h5 class="card-header">
          Top Up Terminals:
        </h5>
        <div class="card-body">
          <ol id="mostUp">

          </ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--End of div.row-->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="card shadow mb-5">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div id="bar-chart">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--End of div.row-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="card shadow mb-5">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div id="lineChart">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 d-flex">
      <div class="card shadow mb-3 w-100">
        <h5 class="card-header">
          Planned vs Unplanned Event
        </h5>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div id="pieChart"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 d-flex">
      <div class="card shadow mb-3 w-100">
        <h5 class="card-header">
          Downtime vs Uptime
        </h5>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div id="pieChart2"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="card shadow mb-5">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div id="barChart2">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="card shadow mb-5">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div id="barChart3">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--END OF div.row-->
  <!--END OF div.row-->
</div>
```

You also have to apply `.w-100` to cards inside `.d-flex` cols, to make them stretch to full column width on smaller responsiveness intervals.

**Important note:** this solution relies on the fact you only have 1 card in each `.col`. If you have more than one, you'll need to add `.flex-column` to your `.col` as well.
But, for your example, `.d-flex` to `.col`s is enough.